# Задача по машинному обучению и футбольным прогнозам

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

В данный момент пишу веб-портал для хранения и обработки данных дворовых матчей. Уже накопилась база за последние 4 года. База состоит из сущностей:
Команда, Игроки, Матчи. В конкретном матче принимают участие две команды. На каждый матч составляется заявка из игроков, которые есть в двух командах, играющих матч.

Хочу реализовать возможность автоматического выставления прогнозов на победу. Прогноз будет зависеть от предыдущих результатов команд, а также от заявки, составленной на конкретный матч. В сторону какого алгоритма из науки о машинном обучении мне нужно копать?

Comment: Полагаясь на то, что все игроки __всегда__ находятся в одинаковой спорт. форме (без учета травм, усталости, настроения, похмелья, и т.д.) и выкладываются __всегда__ одинаково и вас не интересует счет, а только победа (1), проигрыш (-1) или ничья (0) - задача сводится к классификации, где на входе два массива целых чисел (уникальные номера игроков), на выходе число: `-1`, `0` или `1`

Comment: Прежде чем "машинное обучение"  использовать (некоторые методы работают только если петабайты им скормить),  можно обычную статистику использовать. Напоминает эпизод (s03e08) из Numb3rs сериала про бейсбол (sabermetrics, Shiryaev-Roberts change-point analysis)

Answer (score 1):

Это сделать достаточно просто если понимать как работают нейронные сети. Учитывая то какой результат вам нужен я бы посоветовал вам использовать сеть прмяого распространения (**[FeedForward Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network)**). Вы создаете НС и на вход подаете ей парметры закодированные в форме вектора. Так как мы будем оперировать с числами от 1 до -1 то будем использовать [**tangh**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) как функцию активации. Достаточно будет использовать 1 слой скрытых нейронов (примерно 200-1000 нейронов в слою). На выходе у вас будет 3 нейрона соответсвующие исходу матча (выигрыш, проигрыш, ничья).

Алгоритм будет достаточно прост и для этого мы будем использовать унитарный код ([**onehot encoding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)). Суть в том чтобы выбрать все переменный соответсвующие одному параметру и поместить их в так называемый словарь. Этот словарь позже будет преобразован в вектор параметров. Допустим у Вас есть база данных всех игроков. Допустим их 500. Теперь мы берем и помещаем их в словарь. Длинна словаря тоже будет равна 500. Теперь нам нужно закодировать этот словарь под каждую комманду. Для этого мы возьмем наш словарь и запишем его в вектор где каждому игроку будет соответсвовать цифра 0. Теперь возьмем комманду А и сопоставим ее игроков с игроками в нашем векторе и на против них поставим цифру 1. Это будет означать что эти игроки играют за первую комманду. Теперь возьмем комманду B и сопоставим ее игроков с тем же вектором и поменяем 0 на -1. Таким образом у нас получился вектор из игроков где все игроки играющие за первую комманду обозначенны цифрой 1 а за вторую -1, игроки не принимающие участия в матче будут обозначены 0.

Чтобы тренировать НС нужно задать ей не только вход но и выход, поэтому мы должны также указать исход матча и это очень просто. Будем рассматривать исход относительно первой комманды и если она выиграла то нейрон отвечающий за выигрыш будет равен 1, если проигрыш то уже нейрон отвечающий за проигрыш будет равен 1. То есть один из 3 нейронов в выходном слое будет равен 1 а 2 остальных 0. Более подробно о том как тренировать нейронную сеть можно почитать [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation). Надеюсь Вам это поможет!